# Assemble Legend for Many Curves

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, legend

I need to assemble a Matlab/Octave legend for indexed curves, and I found the following example which seems to work well:

```
legend(strcat("curve ", num2str(1:2)))
```

Associates the labels "curve 1" and "curve 2" with the two curves given. However, if I need to add a different, non-indexed type of curve, the method above seems not to work anymore.

```
legend(strcat("curve ", num2str(1:2)),"another curve")
```

In the second example the first curve has for legend ["curve 1"; "curve 2"], and the second curve gets "another curve" for legend, while the last curve gets no legend. I think it has to do with the way legend interprets input, and I'm not able to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

Try assembling the legend as a cell array beforehand, and then using that as the legend input.

```
legendCell = cell.empty
for i = 1:2
   legendCell{i} = ['curve' num2str(i)];
end
legendCell{end+1} = 'another curve';
legend(legendCell);
```

Comment: Thanks that should work. 
It bothers me though to have to use a loop. I had tried with 
label= [];for i=1:2;label = [label;'curve' num2str(i)];end; label= [label;'another curve'] 
which works but gives a 
warning: implicit conversion from numeric to char

Comment: If you know how many entries are going to be in the legend, it would be better to pre-allocate the cell array to the right size, rather than grow its size with each iteration of the `for` loop. With only 2 elements, it won't make a difference, but if you had more, it is good practice.

Comment: If you initialize with `label= ['']` you will get rid of that warning.